# Using a loop to count missing values in the columns of a datset and creating a dictionary with the results

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I am creating a function with a loop because I want to count the missing values in a dataset and add the results to a dictionary. I am using Python on Jupyter lab. This is the code:

```
def find_missing_values(dataframe, columns):
    missing_values = {}
    df_rows = len(dataframe)
    for column in columns:
        tot_column_values = dataframe[column].value_counts().sum()
        missing_values[column] = df_rows - tot_column_values
        return missing_values
    
missing_values = find_missing_values(amazon_data, columns = amazon_data.columns)
missing_values
```

This is the result when I run it:

```
{'uniq_id': 0}
```

I would like it to do the same with all the columns in the dataset (product_name, manufacturer etc.), not only the first one. These are all the columns:

```
amazon_data.columns
```

```
Index(['uniq_id', 'product_name', 'manufacturer', 'price',
       'number_available_in_stock', 'number_of_reviews',
       'number_of_answered_questions', 'average_review_rating',
       'amazon_category_and_sub_category',
       'customers_who_bought_this_item_also_bought', 'description',
       'product_information', 'product_description',
       'items_customers_buy_after_viewing_this_item',
       'customer_questions_and_answers', 'customer_reviews', 'sellers'],
      dtype='object')
```

I do not understand why they are not included in the result/dictionary. Can somebody help me and explain where I am making a mistake, please?

Answer (score 0):

you for loop will return the results after the first iteration

you need to get the `return`  from the loop like this:

```
def find_missing_values(dataframe, columns):
    missing_values = {}
    df_rows = len(dataframe)
    for column in columns:
        tot_column_values = dataframe[column].value_counts().sum()
        missing_values[column] = df_rows - tot_column_values
    return missing_values
```

if you use pandas, you can use `dataframe.isna().sum().to_dict()`.